# How to make class constructor body calls descendant's overriden method/property?

Tags: freepascal, delphi, class-constructors

I'm writing an ORM framework and got stuck in a way to automatically determine table name from class name. In my base object for the ORM to work, I have:

```
TghModel = class
...
  class var FTableName: String;
  class constructor Create;
...
```

whose implementation is:

```
class constructor TghModel.Create;
begin
  FTableName := ClassName;
  Delete(FTableName,1,1); // Delete 'T'
end;
```

My assumption was that ClassName method will return the real class name. e.g. if I have:

```
TUsers = class(TghModel)
```

then FTableName will be initialized to TUsers instead of TghModel, which is wrong. I want to avoid users to make class constructor for each classes inheriting from TghModel, especially because the content would be totally the same as in TghModel.Create. Is there any way to implement it?

P.S.: I'm using Free Pascal as my compiler

Answer (score 1):

I see no way to achieve this as you intended. Even if TUsers got its own class constructor, it would not work because FTableName is shared between TghModel and all child classes. To solve this I see two solutions: create the table name on the fly with something like

```
class function TghModel.TableName : string;
  begin
    Result := ClassName;
    Delete(Result,1,1);
  end;
```

Or if it is speed critical, maybe a generics based solution might be possible?

Comment: Wouldn't ClassName method still produce TghModel? Anyway, I ended up using common solution: export a "register" procedure. that's a very small overhead.

Comment: No. ClassName uses the information of the vmt of the currently handled instance to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

I achived something about you question by this:

```
 class function MyClass.getName:string;
 begin;
  inherited;
  Log_write('~~~~~.getName'+ClassType.ClassName); 
end;
```